# WebResource.axd and IE - Page_ClientValidate object undefined

Tags: 2007, javascript

I have a custom MOSS 2007 Website, and I have a strange behavior on editing WebPart Properties via browser.

When I open the website via Firefox, and edit the webpart property and then click on Apply/OK, it works correctly.

When I do the same via Internet Explorer 8, the Apply/OK button on the webpart properties performs no action at all. I tried debbuging javascripts to find out what's happening, and then I found that when the website is opened using IE, the function Page_ClientValidate is never defined (always return a object undefined), and this funcion is called on the button's action.

What I don't know is why WebResource.axd is not retrieving this information only for IE.

What information can I get to investigate this further, or if anyone have any idea of what's going on.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As bizarre it is, there was some code garbage on some page layout, that included an extra  tag, which did not harm firefox and js, but did on IE.

Good to let it registered here if that happens to someone.

"ALWAYS check the obvious things before going that deep on the analysis."